# getting web url address to detect web proxy

Tags: php, proxy

I'm trying to blocked website based proxy's. These are normally in the format of: 
http://3.hidemyass.com/ip-8/encoded/Oi8vZ29kbGV5ZGVzaWduLmNvLnVrL0xDcmVkaXJlY3QvZnVuY3Rpb25zL2Z1bmN0aW9

My theory of blocking these is to get the URL of the address bar and check that it's actually direct access to my site, rather than visiting via a website proxy.

However, when i try to visit my site and attempt to capture the url of the user it still reports that its my sites url.. not this web based proxy one.

I've tried the following ways of detecting it:

```
$url= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //get the url
$url = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
```

any ideas on how to resolve this?

UPDATE
Ok i've rewrote part of this, however it always seems to be returning false... the $url is being passed correct as i can echo this out within the function. However it doesnt seem to be matching and returning false

```
<script>
var url = window.location.href;
<?php $url = "<script>document.write(url)</script>"; ?> 
</script>

<?php
//
function checkURLIsSafe($url){
    if(preg_match('/www/',$url)){
        echo 'true';
    } else {
        echo 'false';
    }
}
checkURLIsSafe($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP runs on the server. It can only see the URL that was requested from it.

`hidemyass.com` will be requesting the normal URL from your server. There is no way to tell what URL the browser requested from `hidemyass.com`.

Approaches you could take include:

- Checking the source ip against a list of known proxies
- Using client-side JavaScript to read `location.href`

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it with PHP only. What you can do is to check window.location.href with javascript, and if it's incorrect, send ajax request to server, which will block IP address.